# Angular 6 build issue of cannot find module

Tags: angular6, angular-cli

I get this type of error when doing npm start command
[image]

This is tsconfig.json file with minor modification from different people answer on different websites

[image]

Originially it was like but it was giving many more issues hence I modified which reduces to only one issue: 
[image]

Comment: it was marked negative, please answer if you know else please keep your nose aside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...node module was not installed correctly.. running npm install multiple times solved it